# C# dynamically create instance of a datacontext model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to dynamically create an instance of a model and return results like below.  How can I do this?

```
public JsonResult GetDetail(string model, int id)
{
    Type type = Type.GetType("MyProject.WebApplication.Models.MyProjctContext." + model);            
    var result = (type)Activator.CreateInstance(type).Find(id);

    return Json(new
    {
        data = result
    },
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: What does that give you? That looks close to something that should work without doing too much with it.

Comment: I'd think twice about the security aspects of implementing something like this. You're essentially giving direct, unrestricted access to your data layer.

Comment: Add a GetDetail<T> method and overload with a method that takes the type and passes it to a switch/case. But I'm biased to having hardcoded strings in code when you have other alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = (type)Activator.CreateInstance(type).Find(id);
```

1. `CreateInstance(Type)` returns an object which doesn't contains a `Find(int)` method that I believe is found on your *model*.
2. You can't type cast via a type variable, unless it is a specified type in a generic method or generic class method.

This could be fixed by using reflexion, interface :

```
    public JsonResult GetDetail(string modelTypeName, int id)
    {
        var type = Type.GetType("MyProject.WebApplication.Models.MyProjctContext." + modelTypeName);            

        //reflection way
        var model = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        var result = (*find method return type*)type.GetMethod("Find", new Type[] { int }).Invoke(model, new object[] { id });

        //constraint way : with constraint being an interface or a base class that defines .Find(int)
        var result = ((*constraint*)Activator.CreateInstance(type)).Find(id);


        return Json(new
            {
                data = result
            },
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

or using dynamic as Marnix van Valen suggested.

Comment: How would that work with in MVC then? I don't think there's a mechanism in MVC routing and modelbinding that allows a request to be mapped to a generic action method.

Comment: @MarnixvanValen Indeed, I overlooked that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

The only real problem in this code is the cast to `type`. If your data access layer would implement an interface with the method `object Find(int id)` you could simply cast to that interface. Otherwise I would recommend casting to `dynamic` and let the call be resolved at runtime.

```
public JsonResult GetDetail(string model, int id)
{
    Type type = Type.GetType("MyProject.WebApplication.Models.MyProjctContext." + model);            
    var result = ((dynamic)Activator.CreateInstance(type)).Find(id);

    return Json(new
    {
        data = result
    },
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

A couple of remarks about this code:

- Performance will likely not be brilliant.
- This code will blow up if the type does not implement a `Find(int)` method
- Think hard about the security implications of this code. At the very least, limit what entities can be requested through this action.